# Magento reindexing still on Running even after Apache restart

Tags: magento, status, reindex

When I check the status of my reindexing, the Product Prices are stuck on Running even after Apache has been restarted.

- Locks files have been deleted from /var/locks
- Only using CLI

Going nuts.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento stores the status of indexes in `index_process` table. So when a index process fails for example through a timeout or restarting of apache this flag isn't removed. When indexing succeeds this flag is reset or you can set `working` to `pending`. Do you have any exceptions in your Magento logs?

Answer (score 0):

Backup and delete all files under MAGENTO_ROOT/var/locks/

Comment: Oh, shame on me. It's just, I was on a hurry when I saw your question, I just took a chance. Sorry, my bad.